# Eval a variable from db

Tags: smarty

I'm trying to eval a variable that comes from DB. It works in all cases, except one. I can see the variable's value when smarty debug is enabled, but it doesn't get echoed on the page. And this happens only for a particular case.

Is there any known issue with respect to how much data can a smarty variable hold/print?

This is how I eval/echo the variable
{eval var=$custom_js_code}

Kindly note that:

1. $custom_js_code comes from DB and is visible in debug mode
2. The string is wrapped in {literal}

Comment: You'll need to show some code.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question.